# Convert list to set based on duplicate of only certain values of a tuple

Tags: python, python-3.x, set

In general, converting a list to set is simple, as below:

```
a = [1,2,3,1]
set_a = set(a)    # set([1, 2, 3])
```

Now, I want to convert a list of tuples to set, only considering the first value of tuple.

```
a = [(1,"a1"), (2,"b2"), (3, "c3"), (1, "d4")]
set_a = some_magic(a)

# 1) set_a = set([(1,"a1"), (2,"b2"), (3, "c3")]) or
# 2) set_a = set([(1, "d4"), (2,"b2"), (3, "c3")])
# Both (1) or (2) are acceptible outputs.
```

Is there a "one-line" trick I could use instead of `some_magic` function mentioned above?

I want to avoid making a separate list for book-keeping which of the first index of tuples are already used [which would have been the obvious answer otherwise]

Comment: How do you decide  which tuple to keep from `(1,"a1")` and `(1,"d4")` ?

Comment: Either of them are fine.. Have mentioned that in the question as well...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try this:

```
set(dict(a).items())
```

`dict(a)` will turn the list into a dictionary where the keys get overwritten by each occurrence

the `.items()` extracts each key-value pair into a `dict_items` list of tuples

the `set()` turns it into the set you want

Note: this will give you the second example, keeping the very last unique tuple key. If you want the first one, a different approach will be needed

Answer (score 1):

Using list comprehension:

```
a = [(1,"a1"), (2,"b2"), (3, "c3"), (1, "d4")]
seen = set()
print([x for x in a if x[0] not in seen and not seen.add(x[0])])
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
[(1, 'a1'), (2, 'b2'), (3, 'c3')]
```

**EDIT**:

Using a dict:

```
print({x[0]: x for x in a}.values())
```

Answer (score 0):

```
set_a = set(
    {x[0]: x for x in a}.values()
)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can convert to a dictionary to get rid of the duplicates

```
set(dict(a).items())

{(1, 'd4'), (2, 'b2'), (3, 'c3')}
```